# How to work with (commit) two versions simultaneously in GIT?

Tags: android, git, version-control

**THE SITUATION**

I am a fresh android developer and I made an easy application that I want to publish. There are two versions: one free with limitations, and an other without limitations. 99.99 percent of the code is same in the two versions, so I would like to work with them simultaneously. I have already used GIT and version control before, but only to save my data. So the point is I have never used branches.

**THE PROBLEM**

Of course I would like to learn to use the stuff, but now I am looking for a quick solution how to edit both of them.

So I am standing on my last commit and I would like to make the branching, but I have no idea how.

Comment: Reading the first three chapters of [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) is my go-to recommendation for anyone who asks questions like this.

Comment: @moso Have you get the answer which help you solve the problem? If yes, please mark it. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

Steps for git branching :

1) Creating branch :

```
git checkout -b <new-branch-name>
```

2) Checking your current branch :

```
git branch
```

3) Switching branches :

```
git checkout <branch-name>
```

in your case

```
git checkout FREE or git checkout PRO
```

4) Make commits on your checked out branch.

5) For pushing the code to particular branch :

```
git push origin <branch-name>
```

in your case

```
git push origin FREE or git push origin PRO
```

respectively.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please mark the answer correct so that other people can directly refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to create a branch, just run `git branch <branch-name>`. That will create a new branch right on the revision where you are right now. Then you can check it out (`git checkout <branch-name>`) so you can *commit on it* (nothing will the touched on the original branch). Both steps can be achieved at the same time with a single call: `git checkout -b <branch-name>`.

Comment: Plus i would add to this, you have to push code with command
git push origin <branch-name>

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand. Okay it is clear, i have to create two parallel branches: `FREE` and `PRO`. Then what is the next step? How to "edit" both, how to "edit" a single one?

Comment: I will post the whole process in the answer.

Comment: With git with you don't get to work on "both" at the same time. You either work on one branch or the other. What you have to do in order to be able to "exchange" changes between one or the other is either to merge or cherry-pick changes... and it very much depends on the way you "set them up". Say that your free version is the "base" branch and "pro" starts from it and you commit the change to make it pro. You do a change on free, can you merge to pro? Probably...

Comment: ...but the other way around is not that simple because if you merge pro into free, you would merge the change that made it pro... that's why in workflows we talk about "upstream" and "downstream". On this scenario cherry-picking would probably work better. It very much depends on what _you_ want.

Answer (score 0):

Git can’t work with two versions simultaneously, but branches in git can make it separately. So you just need to work on two branches to develop your code based on different versions.

Assume the two versions are `A` and `B`, and they both located on your default branch master. The structure looks like:

```
A---B   master
```

Now you just need to create a new branch from the other version `A` by

```
git checkout -b dev <commit id for A>
```

Then  your branch structure will look like:

```
A---B   master
 \
   …    dev
```

Then you can make change and commit separately for this two branches. For one time you can just make/commit changes for a branch since there has the same working directory.

Such as when you are working on `dev` branch (HEAD point to it), you can just make/commit changes based on version `A`. Then you can switch HEAD to point `master` by `git checkout master`, then make changes and use `git add .` and `git commit -m 'message'` to commit changes.

Finally you can use `git push origin branchname` to push to remote.